Material for Absorbent Cylinder in Ultrasonic Humidifiers
I’m working on a project using micro-perforated ultrasonic cells for plant cultivation, and during benchmarking of commercial humidifiers, I came across a design that uses an absorbent cylinder to supply water to the ultrasonic cell and a spring to maintain the correct pressure of the cylinder on the ultrasonic cell. Can anyone advise on the materials used for the absorbent cylinder in such applications?
Any insights would be helpful!


what does the material look like? ... what other material is similar?

Hi! Sorry for the late response.
It’s a spongy material, similar to cigarette filters, but significantly harder. It has elongated cavities in its structure. I did some more research and ordered some filters that are used in commercial humidifiers, like those in inhalers for administering medication, and I have to say they’re practically identical (although I don’t have a microscope to examine them in more detail). In Amazon can be found with the following text: “ Sticks Filter Replacement Wicks for Portable Ultrasonic Aroma Diffuser Wick”
